Proof or a counter example for $\sum\log(x_i) = \sum\log(y_i)$ has no solutions in prime numbers.
As indicated by the title, I am endeavoring to demonstrate the following assertion or find a counter-example for it.
The equation
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\log(x_i) = \sum_{j=1}^m\log(y_j)$$
holds no solutions in prime numbers. It is crucial to note that all $x_i$ and $y_i$ are distinct primes; in other words, there exists at least one distinct prime number on each side.
In essence, I am seeking to establish that there are no prime numbers $x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n$ and $y_1, \cdots, y_m$, where $n$ and $m$ are arbitrary positive integers, that satisfy the aforementioned equation. It's worth noting that while identical prime numbers on both sides would fulfill the equation, this scenario is not under consideration.
Any insights or suggestions on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Note that $\log(a)+\log(b)=\log(ab)$

Just raise e to both powers.  $\sum \log(x_i) = \sum \log(x_i)\implies e^{\sum \log x_i} = e^{\sum \log x_i} \implies \prod x_i = \prod y_i$ implies two prime factorizations of an integer.  Prime factorizations are unique.

@MichalAdamaszek Thanks! But ab is not a prime number anymore!

@fleablood Thank you very much!!! Simple and perfect!

$\log(a)+\log(b)=\log(ab)$ so your equation reduces to $$x_1x_2\dots x_n=y_1y_2\dots y_m$$
Due to uniqueness of prime factorisation, the $x_i$s and $y_j$s are identical, and so there are no solutions in primes.
Hope this helps. :)
